# Can one encode binary functions between types in OCaml?

Tags: types, ocaml, multiple-dispatch

I am wondering if it is possible to build something similar to multiple dispatch in OCaml. To do that, I tried to make an explicit type for the input signature of a multimethod. As an example, I define a number type

```
type _ num =
| I : int -> int num
| F : float -> float num
```

Now I would like a function `add` to sum an `'a num` and a `'b num` and return an `int num` if both `'a` and `'b` are `int`, and a `float num` if at least one of them is a `float`. Also, the type system should know which constructor the output will use. I.e. it should be statically known at the function call that the output is of type `int num` for example.

Is that possible? So far I can only manage a function of signature `type a b. a num * b num -> a num` for example, so that the (more general) float would always have to be supplied as the first argument. The case `int num * float num` would have to be disallowed, leading to a non-exhaustive pattern match and runtime exceptions.

It seems that one would need a signature like `type a b. a num * b num -> c(a,b) num` where `c` is a type function which contains the type promotion rules. I don't think OCaml has this. Would open types or objects be able to capture this? I'm not looking for the most general function between types, it's enough if I can list a handful of input type combinations and the corresponding output type explicitly.

Comment: what are `'a t`, `'b t`? what is "`'a` and `'b` ints"?

Comment: this was a typo, i edited the question to clarify hopefully

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specific case you are asking about can be solved nicely using GADTs and polymorphic
variants. See calls to `M.add` at the bottom of this code:

```
type whole = [ `Integer ]
type general = [ whole | `Float ]

type _ num =
  | I : int -> [> whole ] num
  | F : float -> general num

module M :
sig
  val add : ([< general ] as 'a) num -> 'a num -> 'a num

  val to_int : whole num -> int
  val to_float : general num -> float
end =
struct
  let add : type a. a num -> a num -> a num = fun a b ->
    match a, b with
    | I n, I m -> I (n + m)
    | F n, I m -> F (n +. float_of_int m)
    (* Can't allow the typechecker to see an I pattern first. *)
    | _,   F m ->
      match a with
      | I n -> F (float_of_int n +. m)
      | F n -> F (n +. m)

  let to_int : whole num -> int = fun (I n) -> n

  let to_float = function
    | I n -> float_of_int n
    | F n -> n
end

(* Usage. *)
let () =
  M.add (I 1)  (I 2)  |> M.to_int   |> Printf.printf "%i\n";
  M.add (I 1)  (F 2.) |> M.to_float |> Printf.printf "%f\n";
  M.add (F 1.) (I 2)  |> M.to_float |> Printf.printf "%f\n";
  M.add (F 1.) (F 2.) |> M.to_float |> Printf.printf "%f\n"
```

That prints

```
3
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000
```

You cannot change any of the above `to_float`s to `to_int`: it is statically
known that only adding two `I`s results in an `I`. However, you can change the
`to_int` to `to_float` (and adjust the `printf`). These operations readily compose and propagate the type information.

The foolery with the nested `match` expression is a hack I will ask on the
mailing list about. I've never seen this done before.

---

### General type functions

AFAIK the only way to evaluate a general type function in current OCaml requires
the user to provide a witness, i.e. some extra type and value information. This
can be done in many ways, such as wrapping the arguments in extra constructors
(see answer by @mookid), using first-class modules (also discussed in next
section), providing a small list of abstract values to choose from (which
implement the real operation, and the wrapper dispatches to those values). The
example below uses a second GADT to encode a finite relation:

```
type _ num =
  | I : int -> int num
  | F : float -> float num

(* Witnesses. *)
type (_, _, _) promotion =
  | II : (int, int, int) promotion
  | IF : (int, float, float) promotion
  | FI : (float, int, float) promotion
  | FF : (float, float, float) promotion

module M :
sig
  val add : ('a, 'b, 'c) promotion -> 'a num -> 'b num -> 'c num
end =
struct
  let add (type a) (type b) (type c)
      (p : (a, b, c) promotion) (a : a num) (b : b num) : c num =
    match p, a, b with
    | II, I n, I m -> I (n + m)
    | IF, I n, F m -> F (float_of_int n +. m)
    | FI, F n, I m -> F (n +. float_of_int m)
    | FF, F n, F m -> F (n +. m)
end

(* Usage. *)
let () =
  M.add II (I 1) (I 2)  |> fun (I n) -> n |> Printf.printf "%i\n";
  M.add IF (I 1) (F 2.) |> fun (F n) -> n |> Printf.printf "%f\n"
```

Here, the type function is `('a, 'b, 'c) promotion`, where `'a`, `'b` are
arguments, and `'c` is the result. Unfortunately, you have to pass `add` an
instance of `promotion` for `'c` to be ground, i.e. something like this won't
(AFAIK) work:

```
type 'p result = 'c
  constraint 'p = (_, _, 'c) promotion

val add : 'a num -> 'b num -> ('a, 'b, _) promotion result num
```

Despite the fact that `'c` is completely determined by `'a` and `'b`, due to the GADT; the compiler still sees that as basically just

```
val add : 'a num -> 'b num -> 'c num
```

Witnesses don't really buy you much over just having four functions, except that
the set of operations (`add`, `multiply`, etc.), and the argument/result type
combinations, can been made mostly orthogonal to each other; the typing can be
nicer and things can be slightly easier to use and implement.

**EDIT** It's actually possible to drop the `I` and `F` constructors, i.e.

```
val add : ('a, 'b, 'c) promotion -> 'a -> 'b -> `c
```

This makes the usage much simpler:

```
M.add IF 1 2. |> Printf.printf "%f\n"
```

However, in both cases, this is not as composable as the GADT+polymorphic variants solution, since the witness is never inferred.

---

### Future OCaml: modular implicits

If your witness is a first-class module, the compiler can choose it for you
automatically with modular implicits. You can try this code in the
`4.02.1+modular-implicits-ber` switch. The first example just wraps the GADT witnesses from the previous example in modules, to get the compiler to choose them for you:

```
module type PROMOTION =
sig
  type a
  type b
  type c
  val promotion : (a, b, c) promotion
end

implicit module Promote_int_int =
struct
  type a = int
  type b = int
  type c = int
  let promotion = II
end

implicit module Promote_int_float =
struct
  type a = int
  type b = float
  type c = float
  let promotion = IF
end

(* Two more like the above. *)

module M' :
sig
  val add : {P : PROMOTION} -> P.a num -> P.b num -> P.c num
end =
struct
  let add {P : PROMOTION} = M.add P.promotion
end

(* Usage. *)
let () =
  M'.add (I 1) (I 2)  |> fun (I n) -> n |> Printf.printf "%i\n";
  M'.add (I 1) (F 2.) |> fun (F n) -> n |> Printf.printf "%f\n"
```

With modular implicits, you can also simply add untagged floats and ints. This example corresponds to dispatching to a function "witness":

```
module type PROMOTING_ADD =
sig
  type a
  type b
  type c
  val add : a -> b -> c
end

implicit module Add_int_int =
struct
  type a = int
  type b = int
  type c = int
  let add a b = a + b
end

implicit module Add_int_float =
struct
  type a = int
  type b = float
  type c = float
  let add a b = (float_of_int a) +. b
end

(* Two more. *)

module M'' :
sig
  val add : {P : PROMOTING_ADD} -> P.a -> P.b -> P.c
end =
struct
  let add {P : PROMOTING_ADD} = P.add
end

(* Usage. *)
let () =
  M''.add 1 2  |> Printf.printf "%i\n";
  M''.add 1 2. |> Printf.printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Very nice!  Sadly verbose in current OCaml, but still impressive type-wise.  On the modular implicits side this does a nice job of illustrating how they will/would be used.  Thank you!

Comment: Modified the `add` function so that the `match` has an exhaustiveness check.

Comment: great, the first part of the answer is what i had not succeeded in doing. what i was missing was to type ``I : int -> [> whole ] num`` with an open variant. not sure how extensible that is to more complicated subtyping relations that int and float but i'll try.

Comment: Yes, it took a bit of effort to work out. This is some kind of heavy abuse of the type system :) I wouldn't expect it to be generally useful, but maybe you can come up with something crazy and elegant :)

Comment: I was looking for something akin your first solution. Brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

OCaml, as of the 4.04.0 release, does not have a way to encode type-level dependencies in this way.  The typing rules would have to be more simple.

One option is to use a simple variant type for this, wrapping everything into one (potentially large) type and match:

```
type vnum =
  | Int of int
  | Float of float

let add_vnum a b =
  match a, b with
  | Int ia, Int ib -> Int (ia + ib)
  | Int i, Float f
  | Float f, Int i -> Float (float_of_int i +. f)
  | Float fa, Float fb -> Float (fa +. fb)
```

Another approach is to restrict the input values to have matching types:

```
type _ gnum =
  | I : int -> int gnum
  | F : float -> float gnum

let add_gnum (type a) (x : a gnum) (y : a gnum) : a gnum =
  match x, y with
  | I ia, I ib -> I (ia + ib)
  | F fa, F fb -> F (fa +. fb)
```

Finally, the type of one of the input values could be used to constrain the return value's type.  In this example the return value will always have the same type as the second argument:

```
type _ gnum =
  | I : int -> int gnum
  | F : float -> float gnum

let add_gnum' (type a b) (x : a gnum) (y : b gnum) : b gnum =
  match x, y with
  | I i1, I i2 -> I (i1 + i2)
  | F f1, F f2 -> F (f1 +. f2)
  | I i, F f -> F (float_of_int i +. f)
  | F f, I i -> I (int_of_float f + i)
```

Comment: thanks! the first option is what i had tried; what i am missing there is that the output is just the full variant, not a specific constructor. the second option gives specific output but i actually want to promote the types to allow int + float. the last idea i also thought of a bit but actually the F f, I i case does not have the semantics i want. i was thinking of leaving it away, leading to possible runtime match failures. bummer.

Comment: i was thinking of open variants to incorporate subtyping but did not succeed so far. something like ``type i = [> `Int]`` for anything that can contain an int, i.e. int, float, a rational. the float type would then be ``type f = [`Float| `Int]`` explicitly including the possibility that it's an int. then the promotion would have to look like: `add: ('a, 'b) -> ['a|'b] ` where `'a` and `'b` would be `i` or `f`. so far this did not work though.

Comment: accepting the answer since subtyping with open variants also does not seem to allow type arithmetic in the way that is needed. it seems impossible to get a function type of the form `'a t -> 'b t -> ['a t|'b t]` even if `'a t` is defined in such a way that it is known to be a polymorphic variant.

Comment: @hcarty see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use subtyping with argument tupling, which allows to reuse some code (that's why subtyping is used):

```
type intpair = [`int_int of int * int]
type floatpair = [`float_float of float * float]

type num = [`int of int | `float of float]

type pair =
  [ `float_int of float * int
  | `int_float of int * float
  | intpair | floatpair ]

let plus_int_int = function `int_int (i,j) -> `int (i+j)
let plus_float_float = function `float_float (x,y) -> `float (x+.y)
let plus_int_float = function `int_float (i,y) -> `float(float i +. y)
let plus_float_int = function `float_int (x,j) -> `float(x +. float j)

let plus
  : pair -> num
  = function
    | `int_int _ as a -> plus_int_int a
    | `float_float _ as a -> plus_float_float a
    | `int_float _ as a -> plus_int_float a
    | `float_int _ as a -> plus_float_int a
```

Now if you want static guaranties, you need to use GADTs:

```
type 'a num =
  | Int : int -> int num
  | Float : float -> float num

type 'a binop =
  | Intpair : (int * int) -> int binop
  | Int_Float : (int * float) -> float binop
  | Float_Int : (float * int) -> float binop
  | Floatpair : (float * float) -> float binop

let plus :
  type a . a binop -> a num
  = function
    | Intpair (a,b) -> Int (a+b)
    | Int_Float (a,y) -> Float (float a +. y)
    | Float_Int (x,b) -> Float (x +. float b)
    | Floatpair (x,y) -> Float (x +. y)
```

Comment: nice! the plus function gives a typed output. however one has to explicitly state the input pair type. the first version of @antron 's answer does that, so i'm accepting that.

Comment: Note also that this interface is logically equivalent to the example I gave with the separate helper GADT (`('a, 'b, 'c) promotion`), except that using a separate third argument is guaranteed not to allocate (though you may have to wrap the constructors in predeclared values (`let ii = II`), haven't checked). On the other hand, wrapping the two arguments in a constructor, as here, will allocate, unless the optimizer can prove that it is not necessary.